# SQL count distinct values for records but filter some dups

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, distinct, survey

I have a MS SQL 2008 table of survey responses and I need to produce some reports.  The table is fairly basic, it has a autonumber key, a user ID for the person responding, a date, and then a bunch of fields for each individual question.  Most of the questions are multiple choice and the data value in the response field is a short varchar text representation of that choice.

What I need to do is count the number of distinct responses for each choice option (ie. for question 1, 10 people answered A, 20 answered B, and so forth).  That is not overly complex.  However, the twist is that some people have taken the survey multiple times (so they would have the same User ID field).  For these responses, I am only supposed to include the latest data in my report (based on the survey date field).  What would be the best way to exclude the older survey records for those users that have multiple records?

Comment: Can you please show your table structure, sample data, desired results, and any query you might have already tried? Working from your actual specs is going to be much faster and easier than creating a solution from scratch out of a word problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't give us your DB schema I've had to make some assumptions but you should be able to use row_number to identify the latest survey taken by a user.

```
with cte as 
    (
         SELECT 
              Row_number() over (partition by userID, surveyID order by id desc) rn,
              surveyID 
          FROM 
              User_survey
    )
SELECT 
       a.answer_type,
       Count(a.anwer) answercount
FROM
      cte 
      INNER JOIN Answers a 
      ON cte.surveyID  = a.surveyID 

 WHERE
      cte.rn = 1
 GROUP BY 
     a.answer_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient query, but what about:

select userid, max(survey_date) from my_table group by userid

then you can inner join on the same table to get additional data.